# WCF customBinding with client certificate

Tags: wcf, soap, certificate

I am trying to create a `customBinding` to call a web service with SOAP 1.2, TLS and a client certificate. As I undestand, this only works with `customBinding`.

I have defined the following behaviour:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TehRightBehaviour">
            <clientCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate>
                    <defaultCertificate findValue="WebInterface" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                    <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck" certificateValidationMode="None" />
                </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The client does find the certificate, if I specify a wrong name, it raises and error. My binding looks like:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="TehRealBinding">
        <transactionFlow />
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
        <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" />
        <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

And I combine it in the end point like:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://hestia1:8081/cm/main"
        behaviorConfiguration="TehRightBehaviour"
        binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="TehRealBinding"
        contract="BrightMain.CMMainService"
        name="cmmain" />
</client>
```

The problem is, if I call the web service, it raises an Exception saying

> "The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials."

I found that there are several points to specify certificates and obviously I am using the wrong one. So my question is: which is the right one?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

**Edit:** Perhaps, I should learn to read, because specifying the `<serviceCertificate>` is obivously not suffictient. I will check this now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should be like this

```
<behavior name="TehRightBehaviour">
    <clientCredentials>
        <!-- clientCertificate not defaultCertificate -->
        <clientCertificate findValue="WebInterface" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck" certificateValidationMode="None" />
        </serviceCertificate>
    </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

Comment: I found that myself in the meantime, too. One addition: at least in my case, the <defaultCertificate> in the <serviceCertificate> tag is required, too.

Answer (score 1):

I Installed the certificate under "Personal" and used following code and it worked for me.

```
X509Store keystore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);              
keystore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certificates = keystore.Certificates;
foreach (var certificate in certificates)
{
    var friendlyName = certificate.FriendlyName;
    var xname = certificate.GetName();
}
X509Certificate certificatex = certificates[0];
X509Certificate2Collection certs = keystore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.
            FindBySubjectName, "Name of subject", false);
```

and then you will pass it in your client request

```
xyzClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certs[0];
```